# Pulling data back to the blade without refreshing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

So I'm pretty new to laravel in general, and what I have is a search form that pulls information from the database and then calls it back on the same page, currently it's working like a redirect but I would like to know how to do this without having to refresh the page

This is the blade:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="policy-documents-search-form" action="/search" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Enter your policy number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber" class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('ordernumber') }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

                @if (session('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ session('error') }}</div>
                @endif

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search-button">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="container">
                    @if(isset($order))
                    <h2>Your Policy Details</h2>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Claims Telephone</th>
                                <th>Policy Wording</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ @$order->scheme->Description }}</td>
                                <td>{{ @$order->scheme->ClaimsTelephone1 }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ @$order->scheme->PolicyURL }}">Policy Wording </a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @endif
                </div>


                </div>
            </div>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is the Controller function:

```
public function search(Request $request) {

    if ($this->validate($request, [
        'ordernumber' => 'string|min:8|max:16',
    ], [
        'ordernumber.string' => ' Please enter a full order number. This will either be 8, 12 or 16 characters long and include a 2 letter prefix.',
        'ordernumber.min' => ' Please enter a full order number. This will either be 8, 12 or 16 characters long and include a 2 letter prefix.',
        'ordernumber.max' => ' Please enter a full order number. This will either be 8, 12 or 16 characters long and include a 2 letter prefix.',
    ]));

        try {
        $order = Order::findOrFail(decodeFullOrderNumber($request->ordernumber));
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return back()->withError('We could not find this policy number in our system, please try again')->withInput();
        }
        return view('policy_wording', compact('order'), [
            'title' => "Policy Wording Results",
        ]);
}
```

And this is the route:

```
 Route::get('/policy-wording', 
'PolicyWordingController@policyWordingPage');
 Route::any('/search', 'PolicyWordingController@search');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with AJAX, you need a front end solution, like Axios or jQuery, in order to make the AJAX requests.

Once the request is sent, you can handle it like a regular POST request and then return a JSON or a html.

For JSON, it's pretty simple, every array or model you return will be converted to JSON by default.

To return a view however, you need to use the render method. This method will "render" the view and return you the corresponding HTML.

So, instead of :

```
return view('policy_wording', compact('order'), [
    'title' => "Policy Wording Results",
]);
```

you should have something like :

```
return view('policy_wording', compact('order'), [
    'title' => "Policy Wording Results",
])->render(); //notice the render method here
```

Then all you need to do is to handle the response in your front-end.

### Edit about validation

If your validation fails, it'll return a 422 error (Unprocessable Entity), so you can handle it like any other ajax error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest to use Vuejs for that purposes so u can not think about how to rebuild your table, etc.

On the serverside all you need to do is return search result if was ajax

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    return $order->toArray();
```

before `return view()`